# Get and submit multiple selection buttons values range

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm trying to submit multiple buttons and use them as range selectors.

In `page1.php` I have `$array` of years `1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, ...` which range is updated by database content:

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php"> 
   <?php
   foreach ($array as $item) {
   ?>
        <input type="submit" name="<?= $item ?> " class="button" value="<?= $item ?> " />                                                      
   <?php
   }
   ?>
</form>
```

this way I can't click two buttons one after another to set the range, for example from 2000 to 2010, and submit only after this action.

I've tried JavaScript function with `onclick` without the `post` method, which counts clicks and pushes two (first and second) clicks values as  range  to the resettable `$rangeval` array before `if (count == 2)` condition comes true, passing   values to second `JavaScript` function `request(input)` from `page1.php` using `ajax`, requesting `page2.php` with `if (isset($_POST['val1']) && isset($_POST['val2']))` and `echo json_encode($array);`, which returns an array as the `result` variable with `JSON.parse(res)` back to `page1.php`.

As PHP runs on the server, I can't process the `JavaScript` `Ajax` response array as `PHP` array in `page1.php`.

So, I'm trying to find some correct method to archive this result.

Any advice, guide, or example would be useful.

Comment: `can't process the JavaScript Ajax response array as PHP array in page1.php.`...no, but you can use JavaScript to update the page however you like

Comment: And/or, instead of using buttons, what about checkboxes?

Comment: @ADyson Hello,  I've PHP foreach ($posts_run as  $postitems) with $postitems['image']; and other $postitems data in HTML tags on the page1.php with page load, which must be replaced according to selected dates range search after submitting

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I also was wondering if it is someway  possible to make it look like a button with color highlighting for selected once

Comment: @emss You can do that with checkboxes or radios by styling the `<label>` element that complements the input element.

Comment: Yep. You can make anything look like pretty much anything else with a bit of CSS

Comment: https://codepen.io/attilahajzer/pen/WbbLpe is just one of [many many resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+make+checkbox+look+like+button) which can help you achieve the visual style.

Comment: With the checkbox idea you should be able to just use your first code snippet, but replace `<input type="submit"` with `<input type="checkbox"`, add any extra CSS you need in order to style the checkboxes, and then continue as before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons in a form and with `type="submit"` will immediately *submit* the form. So buttons are not the correct candidate here.

I would recommend using two `<select>` elements where in you loop over the `$array` to create the options.

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php"> 
  <select name="range_start">
    <?php foreach ($array as $item) : ?>
      <option value="<?= $item ?>"><?= $item ?></option>            
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>

  <select name="range_end">
    <?php foreach ($array as $item) : ?>
      <option value="<?= $item ?>"><?= $item ?></option>            
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>        

  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit values" />  
</form>
```

When submitting read out the `name` attributes that the `<select>` elements have in the `$_POST` array.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['range_start']) && isset($_POST['range_end'])) {
  $range_start = $_POST['range_start'];
  $range_end = $_POST['range_end'];
}
```